# How to connect Apple HDMI to HDMI Cable to IBM Laptop?

Tags: ipad, screen-sharing, display-adapter

I just bought an Apple digital TV adapter. I have an iPad2.

I know, to share my iPad screen, Just connect iPad to Adapter & then connect Adapter second end to Monitor/Screen.

My question is as follows.

- I do have a laptop. Is there a way to produce output of iPad into my laptops screen ?
- Actually, I am already sharing my laptop's screen on a projector.

I can share my screen of laptop. & when I need to share ipad screen, I will start screen of iPad into my laptop & laptop screen will be appeared on projector. I know this sounds ridiculous, But this is what I want to achieve. As, I am not demonstrating fully on iPad. iPad demonstration is for few minutes only.

Comment: Use logme in for Ipad?  umm or someother software to share the ipads screen via wifi.. or remote into the ipad.. You cannot plught the HDMI into the Laptops HDMI, noth ports are outgoing.. You would have to plug the ipad into the projector for the few mintues, then change  cables..

Answer (score 0):

There is no [practical] way to bring the *video signal* of your iPad to your laptop.

Standard practice is to hook up both devices to the projector and switch input on that - you can use an external switcher if your projector only has one input.

Another idea would be to run an [AirPlay Mirror server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPlay#Implementations) on your laptop and use that to display (over WiFi network) the video signal of the iPad2 on the laptop.

Last but not least, you could maybe do all your presentations via the iPad, if you don't have to show off o.s.-specific stuff. If it's just presentations or PDFs you're set to go with your iPad2 and maybe [Apple Keynote for iOS](http://www.apple.com/ipad/from-the-app-store/apps-by-apple/keynote.html)